# How to change the coloring scheme of Gdiff in vim-fugitive plugin?

Tags: linux, vim, color-scheme, git-diff, vim-fugitive

I use the vim-fugitive plugin to check git diff. The coloring scheme to highlight the code changes does not compliment my solarized background. I am not able to see the commands to change the coloring scheme of Gdif. Could anyone help me changing the coloring scheme?

Answer (score 3):

From `:help :diffupdate`:

> ```
> |hl-DiffAdd|    DiffAdd     Added (inserted) lines.  These lines exist in
>                             this buffer but not in another.
> |hl-DiffChange| DiffChange  Changed lines.
> |hl-DiffText|   DiffText    Changed text inside a Changed line.  Vim
>                             finds the first character that is different,
>                             and the last character that is different
>                             (searching from the end of the line).  The
>                             text in between is highlighted.  This means
>                             that parts in the middle that are still the
>                             same are highlighted anyway.  Only "iwhite" of
>                             'diffopt' is used here.
> |hl-DiffDelete| DiffDelete  Deleted lines.  Also called filler lines,
>                             because they don't really exist in this
>                             buffer.
> ```

So, for example, something like

```
:highlight DiffAdd ctermfg=253 ctermbg=237 guifg=#dadada guibg=#3a3a3a
```

in your colorscheme should change the colour of the added lines.